# Class declaration within a function declaration

Tags: c++, function, class

Consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(class B, B *b); 

B *c; //OK

int main(){ }
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e5b752ca449fe68b)**

The Standard `N4296::3.3.2/7.1 [basic.scope.pdecl]`

> — for a declaration of the form
>
> *class-key attribute-specifier-seqopt identifier;*
>
> the identifier is declared to be a class-name in the scope that
>   contains the declaration

, but according to `N4296:3.3.4/1 [basic.scope.proto]`

> In a function declaration, or in any function declarator except the
>   declarator of a function definition (8.4), names of parameters (if
>   supplied) have function prototype scope, which terminates at the end
>   of the nearest enclosing function declarator.

So, the `class B` should have been introduced in the function prototype scope. And the scope of `B` should have been up to the end of the `foo`'s declarator. But the name is visible in the global scope. Why?

Comment: I don't know, but GCC 4.7 accepts this too.  I'm really curious how you came up with this construction in the first place!

Comment: The first quote doesn't apply. There's no semicolon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are quoting the wrong bullet in 3.3.2 [basic.scope.pdecl]/p7. The `class B` in the declaration of `foo` is not of the form `class-key attribute-specifier-seq_opt identifier;` - there is no semicolon.

Instead, the second bullet applies:

> for an *elaborated-type-specifier* of the form
>
> *class-key identifier*
>
> if the *elaborated-type-specifier* is used in the *decl-specifier-seq*
>   or *parameter-declaration-clause* of a function defined in namespace
>   scope, the identifier is declared as a *class-name* in the namespace
>   that contains the declaration; otherwise, except as a friend
>   declaration, the identifier is declared in the smallest namespace or
>   block scope that contains the declaration.

Hence, the *elaborated-type-specifier* `class B` in your example declares `B` as a *class-name* in the namespace containing the declaration of `foo` - i.e., the global namespace.